# Tcpdf throws an error when it cannot find an image

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF to build PDFs. And when it cannot reach an image, it stops execution with an error saying:

```
    Warning: getimagesize(files/ckeditor/76c2ca4259823aa325f0992607726b33.jpeg): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

But, the problem is that this warning is throwing an exception, instead of failing and chugging on.

I'm using this to track for errors

```
            define('K_TCPDF_THROW_EXCEPTION_ERROR', true);
```

Which I used to prevent it from die() due to this code

```
public function Error($msg) {
    // unset all class variables
    $this->_destroy(true);
    if (defined('K_TCPDF_THROW_EXCEPTION_ERROR') AND !K_TCPDF_THROW_EXCEPTION_ERROR) {
        die('<strong>TCPDF ERROR: </strong>'.$msg);
    } else {
        throw new Exception('TCPDF ERROR: '.$msg);
    }
}
```

The question is - how do I prevent it from throwing an exception when it cannot find an image?

Cos the alternative I found is silently die-ing.

Comment: `try` and `catch`

Comment: I need it to not throw an exception. I'm catching it. But i don't need the exception to happen when it cannot find an image

Comment: why not fix the errors instead?

Comment: @IgorQ. `getimagesize` function is not part of `TCPDF` meaning your not going to find the error with `K_TCPDF_THROW_EXCEPTION_ERROR`.

Comment: @hcoat mind... blown. Derped good.